# How to install JSON for Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: json, visual-studio-2012, reference, package, visual-studio-2013

I Installed the Nuget Package Installer thing, and it says it installed it.
However I can't find any references to JSON in Visual Studio.

I tried using System.JSON but I can't find it.
How can I use it?
Thanks

Comment: What package? What language?

Comment: Did you look in your project's references?

Comment: @SLaks It's in C#. The JSON package. And when I go to add references there is none.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had been through the same trouble today, when I almost completed my Software Project and just had to use the File to use its contents to change the content of the Project.

For that I wanted to use `JsonObject` class to get the contents of the **.json** file. When I tried to write this

```
using System.Json;
```

It gave me the exact same error that you might have been going through. It asked for the Assembly files and DLLs.

I kept searching and I stumbled upon to this post, which was totally unhelpfull for me. So I searched and got what I was looking for. After that, I wanted to share that triumph with you people too so that next visitor **must have** an answer to his trouble on Stack Overflow.

#### Solution

What I did was, I went to the NuGet website for the `System.Json` extension package.

http://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Json

There, I capture the command for the installation.

I just click on the `Tools --> NuGet package manager --> Package Manager Console` and it gave me a new window in the bottom part of Visual Studio 2013.

There I typed (pasted) the link of command I copied. It started and installed the package for me. And now I can use it!

#### Further answer

I was told that it is a part of .NET v4.5, but I even have the v4.5.1 and still I don't get it why I don't have that package, maybe because on the Web page of the package it is shown **deprecated**. But still who ever needs it, can have the answer I have posted and it would help him out!

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the Newtonsoft JSON.NET package.

http://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/

Comment: I already installed it using the NUget package manager but I can't find it

Answer (score 0):

I was also looking for a way to do JSON in C# and saw that they made it easier with .NET 4.5, couldn't do it and found this stack overflow question.  I wasn't really satisfied with Afzaal Ahmad Zeeshan's answer so I kept searching and found [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.jsonreaderwriterfactory(v=vs.110).aspx) which I guess isn't depreciated and worked for me.

Steps in plain English (for .NET 4.5):

```
1.Add Reference to System.Runtime.Serialization
2.Add "using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;" to your class
3.call "JsonReaderWriterFactory.CreateJsonReader()" or whatever methods you need to use to read/write json
```

Answer (score -1):

1. Install latest VS 2017
2. Install-Package System.Runtime.Serialization.Json -Version 4.3.0
   -- in PM console